# A scenario in ASP.MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

We are creating an ASP.MVC Application. We are following a MVC pattern. 
In a page, we need to show a chart. Now, my senior suggests me a way which doesn’t follow MVC pattern.

My Way(follow MVC pattern) – On the button click, handle an input request by controller. Controller handles the model and view. View renders the chart on the browser which is simple MVC pattern.

Senior suggestion – Don’t waste your time on Model, controller.(as per him, this process will take extra time.) Direct call to a JS function on the button click. JS function using Ajax call, get the data from the DB and provide the data to chart. Chart will render on the browser.

In above scenario, which way should I follow?

Please suggest.

Comment: Depending on the scenario you could just get the chart data on the first page request and send that in with your model to the view, however if desired functionality is so the user can click a button and the chart will appear I suggest you use Ajax and just return the json you data need. Also http://www.highcharts.com/ is a nice plugin for displaying charts

Comment: we are using AM charts.

Comment: Looking at AM charts i would use an ajax call which just returns some JSON and then pump that into the AM charts `makeChart` method

Answer (score 1):

Since the js function is calling a method of one of your controllers, the MVC pattern is not violated. Just a call to the controller without loading the whole page. Trust your Senior ;-)

Comment: I agree with Joey. Your button would then call a function that would make a javascript call to the webapi method or controller to get the JSON data. Absolutely nothing wrong with that and the only way you can have a truly interactive client-side chart experience.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.